# Delete record binary file c

Tags: c, file, struct, record, binaryfiles

I just made a program to delete a record from a binary file, but the problem is even if the program finds a match with the name, it does't actually delete it from the file when I write the records on a temporary file. Do I get wrong in the else condition perhaps?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    int dd;
    int mm;
    int yyyy;
}date;

struct _food
{
    char category[20];
    char name[30];
    int amount;
    data expiry;
    int calories;
} food;
int main()
{
    FILE* fba;
    FILE* temp;
    int found = 0;
    char nome_t[30];
    char newname[] = "alimenti.bin";
    char oldname[] = "temp.bin";
    fba = fopen("alimenti.bin", "rb");
    temp = fopen("temp.bin", "wb");

    printf("Type the name of the food you want to delete:\n");
    gets(nome_t);
    while(fread(&food,sizeof(food),1,fba))
    {
        if(strcmp(nome_t,food.name) != 0)   
        {
            fwrite(&food,sizeof(food),1,temp);

        }
        else{
            found = 1;
            printf("Match found. Food deleted.\n");

        }

    }
    if (!found){
        printf("No match.\n");

    }

    fclose(fba);
    fclose(temp);
    remove(oldname);
    rename(oldname,newname);
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;


}
```

Comment: Your handle `fba` refers to file named by `newname`, and file handle `temp` refers to file named by `oldname`, but those variable names do not suggest any correspondence. You could try using better names (eg. `fba`/`fba_name` and `temp`/`temp_name`).

Comment: @el.pescado I corrected, I deleted the wrong file so of course nothing changed. After changing that, everything works, thank you

Comment: I mean, if variables relate to same thing, their names should show that relation. That way, if you had `remove(temp_name);` it would be easier to spot error.

Comment: @el.pescado I guess you're right, I'll modify it thank you

Answer (score 3):

You are removing the updated file (*temp.bin*, aka `oldname`) :

```
remove(oldname);
```

before you attempt to replace the original file (*alimenti.bin*, aka `newname`) with it :

```
rename(oldname,newname);
```

Did you mean :

```
remove(newname);
```

Comment: Oh my, thank you! Now it works perfectly! Sorry for this stupid mistake